# Ficus Elastica Robusta - what is wrong with the leaves?

Tags: leaves, ficus

I will be grateful for any advice I can get.

My ficus elastica robusta has been doing quite well so far, during the summer a lot of new leaves sprang and even now a few more are apparently on the way.

Nevertheless, about a 3 weeks ago one of the leaves, one of the new leaves to be precise, started to show some weird spots - to me it seems as if something burned the skin of the leaf such as an acid or similar agent.

Now, the state of the leaf is shown on the photo attached. A few other leaves have small holes in them which look like something pierced them and the edge of the leaf around the hole dried out.

Once more, I do appreciate any help I can get!

[image: Affected leaf]

Comment: Is this an indoor or outdoor plant?

Comment: @Jurp it is an indoor plant, at least it has been for over a year now